# Python - compare columns in a text file, loop and pop lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, text, ordereddictionary

I've got a text file as it follows

```
First col, Second col, Third col, Fourth col,...
```

Similar to this:

```
Johnny, Rodgers, ID1, 18th July,...   
Johnny, Rodgers, ID1, 18th July,...  
Pat, Bryant, ID2, 29th April,...   
Pat, Bryant, ID2, 9th May,... 
Jim, Williams, ID3, 10th March,...  
Jim, Williams, ID3, 17th March,...   
Jim, Williams, ID3, 21st March,...
etc
```

I would like to check if there are repetitions in the 3rd column and, in that case, check if the 4th column is also the same in the rows with repetitions in the 3rd. In case cols 3 and 4 are the same also, delete both rows (the whole row), and if col 4 is different, store the result. After that print/store the result.

This is,
  * If Lines 1, 2 have the same value in col 3 and the same value in the 4th also, delete both lines
  * In case lines 3 and 4 have the same value in col 3 and different in the 4th,  print the rows and count +1
  * If lines 5, 6, and 7 have the same value in col 3 and different in the 4th, print the rows and count +1

So that after executing, the result would be like

```
Pat, Bryant, ID2, 29th April,...   
Pat, Bryant, ID2, 9th May,... 
Jim, Williams, ID3, 10th March,...  
Jim, Williams, ID3, 17th March,...   
Jim, Williams, ID3, 21st March,...

counter = 2 #Number of different ID present
```

My idea is to make two lists and store lines there, but I don't success in setting a target and compare other column at the same time. I would also need to loop and pop with my current logic and I am not doing it well.

```
val = []
duplicated = []

with open('file.txt', 'rt') as myf.
     for line in myf:
            col = line.stip():split(',')
            if col[2] not in val:
                val.append( THE ROW HERE ) #How to copy and parse the row?
            else:
                duplicated.append( THE ROW HERE ) #Same question
#Comparisons

for x in value:
    if x in dupl:
        value.pop(x)
        dupl.pop(x)

counter = len(val) #Counter of total cases not erased
val.extend(duplicated)

### I would like to print the whole set of rows ordered by the 3rd col

for element in val:
    print element

print "counter of cases: " , counter
```

Help and suggestions to improve my coding would be more than welcome.

Comment: Are common lines (lines to be removed) allways adjacent or is it necessary to keep everythin in memory until the end of file ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Hi! they are always adjacent. What I don't know is how many cases of repetition there will be. Usually there will be 2 consecutive rows to compare, but they might be more up to an undetermined value (more than 4 would be really strange, but possible though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they are always adjacent, and using your example data:

```
import csv

with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    header=next(reader)
    data={k:[] for k in header}
    for row in reader:
        row_di={k:v for k,v in zip(header, row)}
        if (all(len(data[e]) for e in header) 
               and row_di['Third col']==data['Third col'][-1] 
               and row_di['Fourth col']==data['Fourth col'][-1]):
            for e in header:
                data[e].pop()
        else:
            for e in header:
                data[e].append(row_di[e])

>>> data
{'Second col': ['Bryant', 'Bryant', 'Williams', 'Williams', 'Williams'], 'First col': ['Pat', 'Pat', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim'], 'Fourth col': ['29th April', '9th May', '10th March', '17th March', '21st March'], 'Third col': ['ID2', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID3', 'ID3'], '...': ['...   ', '... ', '...  ', '...   ', '...']}
```

Printing that in your format:

```
unique_ids=set(data['Third col'])    

while True:                        
    try:    
        print ', '.join([data[e].pop(0) for e in header])
    except IndexError:
        break     
print 'Unique IDs:', len(unique_ids)
```

Prints:

```
Pat, Bryant, ID2, 29th April, ...   
Pat, Bryant, ID2, 9th May, ... 
Jim, Williams, ID3, 10th March, ...  
Jim, Williams, ID3, 17th March, ...   
Jim, Williams, ID3, 21st March, ...
Unique IDs: 2
```

Notes:

1. It is usually better to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for csv data;
2. Use a `set(iterable)` to get the number of unique entries in the iterable;
3. You may consider using a dict of [deques](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) rather than a dict of lists if you have very much data. Deques are a lot faster with pop that this implementation relies on.

Answer (score 1):

I started with your example code, and assumed that lines to be merged and deleted are adjacents. I simply keep values of previous line for the comparison and optionaly add last line.

I use a set for counting the different ids.

I also implemented a sort on kept lines on 3rd field and 4th taken as a dat with the full name of the month in current locale.

Tested in your example, output is what you asked for, even in input lines are shuffled, provided that the 2 lines to remove are adjacent.

Code is :

```
import re
import datetime
val = []

old = None
oldcount = 0
oldcols = None
counter = 0

ids = set()

with open('file.txt', 'rt') as myf:
     for line in myf:
            cols = line.strip().split(',')
            if (old is not None) and (oldcols[2] == cols[2]) \
                   and (oldcols[3] == cols[3]):
                oldcount += 1
            else:
                if oldcount == 1:
                    val.append(old)
                    ids.add(cols[2])
                old = line.strip()
                oldcount = 1
                oldcols = cols

if oldcount == 1:
    val.append(old)
    ids.add(cols[2])

### I would like to print the whole set of rows ordered by the 3rd col
rx = re.compile('\s*([ 0-9]{2}).. *(\w*)')
val.sort(key = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(
    rx.sub('\g<1> \g<2>',x.split(',')[3]),'%d %B'))
val.sort(key = lambda x: x.split(',')[2])
for element in val:
    print (element)

print ("counter of cases: " , len(ids))
```

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you. I give you +1 but I will investiate sth about the other answer before accepting one. 
Greetings!